# How to save a matrix in Compressed row storage (CSR) format if first few rows are empty?

Tags: python, data-structures, compression, sparse-matrix

If a matrix is in the form

```
[0,0,0
 0,0,0
 1,1,1
 0,0,0
 2,2,2]
```

and the indexing starts with 1, the V vector would be `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, C would be `[1,2,3,1,2,3]` and V would be `[1,1,1,2,2,2]`. But then if I want to reach the element `[2,2]` I would get 1 instead of 0, and there is no idicator that some of the rows are empty. How would I implemnt CSR form so this doesn't happen?

This is my Python implementation so far:

```
class CRS:
    def __init__(self, N, M):
        self.N = N
        self.M = M
        self.V = [1,1,1,2,2,2]
        self.C = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
        self.R = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
        self.default_value = np.NAN
    
    def adress(self, i, j):
        if (i>=self.N or j>=self.M):
            print("Index out of range.")
            return
        start = int(self.R[i])
        stop = int(self.R[i+1])
        if (stop<=start):
            return self.default_value
        else:
            for k in range(start, stop):
                if self.C[k] == j:
                    v_index = k
                    break
            return self.V[v_index]
```

Comment: All python indexing, including sparse, starts with 0.

Comment: With your class I get an error: `local variable 'v_index' referenced before assignment`

Answer (score 1):

Using the `scipy.sparse` package, your array is:

```
In [375]: arr = np.array([[0,0,0],
     ...:  [0,0,0],
     ...:  [1,1,1],
     ...:  [0,0,0],
     ...:  [2,2,2]]
     ...:  )

In [376]: arr
Out[376]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2]])

In [377]: M = sparse.csr_matrix(arr)

In [378]: M
Out[378]: 
<5x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [379]: M.A
Out[379]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 2]], dtype=int32)
```

The key arrays are:

```
In [380]: M.indptr, M.indices, M.data
Out[380]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 6]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]),
 array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int32))
```

All 0 rows are identified by the repeated `indptr` values, e.g 0 and 3.

The `indptr` array has N+1 values, one per row plus one.  `indptr[i+1]-indptr[i]` is the number of nonzero (non default) elements in the `i` row.

```
In [410]: np.diff(M.indptr)
Out[410]: array([0, 0, 3, 0, 3])
```

`csr_matrix` has no problems with indexing.  In some cases it's actually implemented with an 'extractor matrix' and matrix multiplication.

```
In [382]: M[1,1], M[2,2],M[1,2:]
Out[382]: 
(0,
 1,
 <1x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>)
```

The same matrix in COO format (`sparse.coo_matrix(arr)`):

```
In [398]: Mo=M.tocoo()
In [399]: Mo
Out[399]: 
<5x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.intc'>'
    with 6 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [400]: Mo.data, Mo.row, Mo.col
Out[400]: 
(array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int32),
 array([2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]))
```

Order of terms in COO isn't important; the CSR format sorts by rows, but doesn't have to be sorted by column within rows.